# Typescript auto formatting has become auto-trashing

Tags: typescript, autoformatting

Typescript autoformatting has become a threat. When I am entering quoted strings (" or `) the rest of the code may become temporarily inverted with other strings appearings as code.

This suddenly has gotten worse a string like

`` `<tag>stuff</tag>${foo}${bar}` ``

will become

`` `< tag>stuff< /tag> ${foo} ${bar} ` ``

which makes the browser unhappy and when I construct path names I find spaces in them!

I'm becoming afraid of VSC and that shouldn't happen. And I don't see which extension is the culprit. I depend on formatting and am glad to request it explicitly (^k^d in my VS binding) but it's now auto-trashing the code!

- How do I track down the culprit and fix it?
- is this new? It seems so. Or did I change a setting?
- I can't be the only one running into this -- or am I?

Answer (score 2):

> Typescript auto formatting has become auto-trashing

This is not due to TypeScript / VSCode default. Some extension is behaving badly.

> How do I track down the culprit and fix it

Disable extensions one by one till you find the culprit. Then remove that extension.